# Do joins in Hive behave differently?

Tags: sql, hadoop, join, hive, left-join

I have two tables t1 containg 3million records and t2 containing 11000 records. I execute the query

```
Select Count(*) FROM 
t1 LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

I execute this query on a sql workbench, it returns 3million which is correct because it is a left join. But when I upload this data to Hive and run the same query it returns 9Million. can anyone explain why this is happening? Do joins behave differently in Hive as compared to normal SQL?

Comment: there might be some issue with the data downloaded to HDFS, try select ID, count(*) from t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id group by t1.id and find which rows are duplicating and use select queries and to find where those rows are coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is not the same.  I would suggest a "histogram of histogram" query to figure out what the issue is:

```
select cnt, count(*), min(id), max(id)
from (select id, count(t2.id) as cnt
      from t1 left join
           t2
           on t1.id = t2.id
      group by id
     ) t
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

This will give an idea of how many non-matches there are; how many onesies, twosies, and so on.

Comment: I figured it out.. There were duplicates in the data

Answer (score 0):

use hive

```
select count(*) from tb1
```

see data number is 3million

tb2 id one-to-many

hive insert date select?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Select COUNT(id) FROM 
t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```